# NetBeans : Making sure that main method exists

Tags: java, netbeans

Every time I create a new Java class inside a net beans project, I want to have the main method created automatically like the following:

```
package sorting;

/**
 *
 * @author me
 */
public class Sorting {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

Does anyone know how can I achieve this in NetBeans 8.0.2 ? I kind of navigated to `Tools-->Options--->Editor` section but I was lost after that and couldn't figure out where to make the necessary changes. Could anyone please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Every time you create a new *project*, it will create a main method. There's no point in having multiple ones per project. Why do you want this?

Comment: It creates one main method with it's first java class when I create a new project, but suppose I want to  create another Java class in the same package, I would like to have main class over there rather than typing the same again and again.

Comment: Is there an auto complete feature that you can just type *main* and then auto complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click on the package in your project in the Netbeans Projects list, select New and then Other... In categories go to Java and in the right side list should be a file named Java Main Class.

The next time that you need it, it should be directly under New

But if you create a new class for your project, it doesn't need to have a main method, you just need a class.

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for. Now I won't have to type main method again and again